# Vaadin QuickTickets Dashboard deploy error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, vaadin7

i tried to compile and run the vaadin demo application but i get the following error. Did i miss something?

i downloaded the code from github https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo tried with

> mvn install
>
> then deployed to Tomcatserver 7.0.47 but i keep getting the following
>   error.
>
> ```
> HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
> ```
>
> type Exception report
>
> message com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:240)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>   root cause
>
> com.vaadin.server.ServiceException:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1440)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1394)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>     java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
>     java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
>     com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.data.DataProvider.createTransaction(DataProvider.java:406)
>     com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.data.DataProvider.generateTransactionsData(DataProvider.java:345)
>     com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.data.DataProvider.(DataProvider.java:53)
>     com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.DashboardUI.(DashboardUI.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
>     com.vaadin.server.UIProvider.createInstance(UIProvider.java:36)
>     com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:200)
>     com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:73)
>     com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
>     com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

and the other error

```
    HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

type Exception report

message com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:240)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1440)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1394)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
    java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
    com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.data.DataProvider.createTransaction(DataProvider.java:406)
    com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.data.DataProvider.generateTransactionsData(DataProvider.java:345)
    com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.data.DataProvider.<init>(DataProvider.java:53)
    com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.DashboardUI.<init>(DashboardUI.java:62)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    com.vaadin.server.UIProvider.createInstance(UIProvider.java:36)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:200)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:73)
    com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

i also tried it with eclipse it is also return the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common exception when you try run this demo. You must fix apiKey in DataProvider.class. In Dashboard example use http://developer.rottentomatoes.com API for getting list of films. Simplest way - create account in that site. It is simple and free.